# Custom server side cache for apollo graphql without data sources

Tags: typescript, caching, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I was wondering if it is possible to set custom server side caching (implementing custom backend cache that implements KeyValueCache) in apollo v4 without data sources in use? I went through the docs and I think I made all the steps as explained but still my cache doesnt work. What I did so far:

1. Implemented custom cache class that implements KeyValueCache
2. Added cacheControl directive to schema, marked a type to use cacheControl directive:

```
    type MyType @cacheControl(maxAge: 30) {
    id: ID!
    }

    type Query {
    getMyType(identifier: ID!): MyType!
    }
```

3. Added cache to ApolloServer constructor:

```
    const server = new ApolloServer({
        schema,
        validationRules: [depthLimit(graphqlQueryDepthLimit)],
        introspection: introspectionAllowed,
        cache: new DynamoDBCache()
    });
```

4. Have a custom resolver defined like:

```
    getMyType: async (_, { identifier }) => {
        return await myTypeService.getMyType(
            identifier
        );
    },
```

Now the question is what am I doing wrong or what I missed from the docs. Do I need to use dataSources to be able to use server side caching? We are not using it, just calling db directly.